# Whats the Difference between (As) and (=) in object declaration in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, declaration

I can create a new object like this:

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)
```

or like this:

```
Dim sqlconn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)
```

What's the difference? Since both worked fine for me!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first one is the short form of:

```
Dim sqlconn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)
```

The second one depends on what version of VB you are using. In VB 7 and VB 8 it is the same as:

```
Dim sqlconn As Object = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(cs)
```

In VB 9 type inference was introduced, so the compiler will infer the type from the assignment and produce the same code as the first one.

The type inference requires that the option `Option Infer` is set to `on`. This is the default setting, but it might be off if you migrate a project from an older version.

Comment: +1 Worth mentioning that types are only inferred if you have `Option Infer On`, otherwise VB9 acts like earlier versions.

Comment: @MarkJ: Good point. It's the default, but it might be off if you migrage a project.

Comment: +1 But, for completeness, it is also worth mentioning the `As Object` interpretation is only allowed when `Option Strict` is `Off` (and `Option Infer Off` or pre-VB9).